# How I certain for sticking my buttons to sides for all of screens with different sizes on android?

Tags: android, xml, button

I am designing a Layout for ones app fro android.
I have in the bottom of my layout an TableLayout which has one row only. This row has 2 columns.
Each column has one linerLayout and in the liner layout is one Button!
I want the buttons stick to the sides of the screen.
I manually define widths for each linerLayout and buttons. But This may be cause distancing from sides for such Screens. How I certain for sticking my buttons to sides for all of screens with different sizes.

```
        <TableLayout
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
                android:id="@+id/linerlistandback"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

                <TableRow 
                     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                     android:gravity="center" 
                     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                     android:layout_width="match_parent">

                     <LinearLayout 
                          android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent">   
                       <ToggleButton
                           android:id="@+id/btnToggleListVideo"
                           android:layout_width="157dp"
                           android:layout_height="40dp"
                           android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                           android:textOn="List"
                           android:textOff="List" 
                           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/item0" 
                           android:paddingLeft="30dp" 
                           android:paddingRight="20dp"/>
                     </LinearLayout>

                     <LinearLayout
                         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                         android:paddingLeft="2dp">
                         <ToggleButton
                             android:id="@+id/toggleRecordingButton"
                             android:layout_width="157dp"
                             android:textOff="Start"
                             android:textOn="Stop" 
                             android:background="@drawable/selector_button" 
                             android:layout_height="40dp" 
                             android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" 
                             android:paddingLeft="30dp" 
                             android:paddingRight="20dp"/>
                     </LinearLayout>

                  </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Try using `gravity:left` and `gravity:right` on the LinearLayouts respectively. And also make sure the table uses the full width change layout width to match_parent. `layout_gravity:left` could be used on the buttons themselves as well.

Comment: can you modify my code???I fair of if i have a mistake when adding your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ToggleButton" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ToggleButton" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: @setareshojaei Just give it a try first. This attribute android:layout_weight="1"  can distribute the width of your toggle buttons evenly, no matter what is the screen width. And it need android:layout_width="0dp" to work.

Comment: you are like a flower!i will try now.